# Python Error "name 'A' is not defined" in class variable initialization

Tags: python, variables, static

This code works in the python command line.  However, when compiling it in a module it gives the following error: "name 'A' is not defined."

```
>>> class A:
...     a = 2
...     c = A.a
... 
>>> A.c
2
```

```
class A:
    a = 2
    c = A.a

NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

I found a better solution.  As shown below, a static variable is available for the initialization of another static variable.  The code below compiles fine.

```
class A:
    a = 2
    b = a

c = A()
print(c.b)
```

Comment: The name `A`  isn't defined until after the `class` block is finished. So you can't reference it while defining the class.

Comment: I suspect in your interactive session you had previously defined the `A` class. So you were using the old value of `A.a`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  But, why does it work in the command line?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. You are correct.  I reset my command line, and then it generated the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is *b/c* the `class` is not defined yet, so you have to put the `c = A.a` outside of the class, or you could do:

```
 class A:
     a = 2
 c = A.a
 print(c)
```

Output:

```
2
```

or, as @Barman replied, you could do also:

```
 class A:
     a = 2
 A.c = A.a
 print(A.c)
```

Out:

```
2
```

Comment: Or `A.c = A.a` to do what he was trying to do.

Comment: @Barmar Ya, I get it now.  I need to define a class variable without initializing it.  Then, if I want to use the other class variables to assign to this class variable, I can do later in my code by using the class name like this: A.b = A.a.